# C Directory and Subdirectory Recursion

Tags: c, directory

I tried to recursively get all files and folder list.But I can only get subdirectories of documents and inside of them.I can't get the other folders which in inside of subdirectory.
I don't know how to do it recursively.I hope you help me

```
          #include <stdio.h>
     #include <sys/types.h>
     #include <dirent.h>
     #include <windows.h>
     #include <unistd.h>
     #include <string.h>
     void list(char *a);
     void reader(char *path);   
     int
     main (void)
     {
       DIR *dp;
       struct dirent *ep;

       dp = opendir ("C:\\Users\\pen\\Documents\\");
       if (dp != NULL)
         {
           while (ep = readdir (dp)){

GetFileAttributes(ep->d_name); 
if(FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY & GetFileAttributes(ep->d_name))
{

        if (strcmp(".",ep->d_name)==0)
            continue;

    if (strcmp("..",ep->d_name)==0)
    continue;



     reader(ep->d_name);

}

             }
             closedir(dp);

         }
       else
         perror ("Couldn't open the directory");
         closedir(dp);
     system("pause");
       return 0;
     }
    void reader(char *path){
            DIR *da;
            struct dirent *ef;
                da = opendir(path);
            while (ef=readdir(da)){
            printf ("%s\n",ef->d_name);
        if(FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY & GetFileAttributes(ef->d_name))
        {

if (strcmp(".",ef->d_name)==0)
continue;


    if (strcmp("..",ef->d_name)==0)
continue;
    reader(ef->d_name);

}
    }
      closedir(da);
}
```

Comment: Directories are not a concept of the C language but of the operating system. Please tag your question correctly such that we know what system your question is about. Also if you look at the right colon of this page you see that a lot of questions have already be asked along that line. Did you read them before posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In `reader` you need  to call `closedir(da);` after the while loop.

2)  every call to `reader` needs to have the absolute path  you need to concatenate `path`

to    `ef->d_name` and then call reader.

3) also to enable debugging  you should call  `perror` after a failed `readdir` call.

Comment: Thanks but it's still same I change the code in the question maybe I made something wrong